# How to find the stock that I just inherited

Tags: united-states, stocks, shares, transfer

My friend passed away Jan 15, 2022.  I was notified this week by the custodian of the will, that I am named in the will as beneficiary of all my friend's General Electric Stock.

I was told that shortly before my friend died, he signed a form, from General Electric and had it notarized.  I don't know if he signed a Transfer of Stock form or a transfer on Death form. Either form should prevent the stock from going thru probate.

The custodian of the will was present when the form was notarized, but has no idea what form was signed only that it had to do the with General Electric Stock.  The custodian does not know if my friend has a broker or if my friend dealt directly with GE. The custodian has idea how many shares of Ge Stock there are .

How can I find out

1. What form my friend signed straight transfer or TOD.
2. How many shares there are
3. If I am now the legal owner of said stocks.

Comment: what country has this all transpired in?

Comment: First, you can ask the custodian of the will to send you all the documents relevant to the fact the you are the beneficiary of the stock. If necessary, you can go 1 step further, and contact a lawyer who can examine the documents and explain everything to you.

Comment: Marin County, California I have a copy of the will It has just been submitted to Probate. But that's not the problem I don't know how to find out if the stock has been transfereed

Comment: @cindy is there a lawyer involved? Do you know who the notary was?

Comment: No lawyer yet.  Do not know the notary but I can find that out from the custodian